# Exercise Relations, Charles C. Pinter Chapter 3

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\text{Let}\hspace{0,1 cm} \mathbb R\hspace{0,1 cm}\text{be  the set of the real numbers, and let R be the following relation in}\hspace{0,1 cm} \mathbb R \times \mathbb R $$

$$ R=\{ [(a,b),(c,d)]: a^{2}+ b^{2}=c^{2}+d^{2} \} $$

> Let $f: \mathbb R\to  \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ be the function given by $f(x)=(\sin(x),\cos(x))$. Describe $\overrightarrow f(R)$. What are its equivalence classes?

This is my work done:

$$f =\begin{cases}\mathbb R\to  \mathbb R \times \mathbb R
\,  &  \\[2ex]
x\to  f(x)=(\sin(x),\cos(x))
\end{cases}$$

$$\overrightarrow f(R)=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R\to  \mathbb R:[(\sin(x),\cos(x)), (\sin(y),\cos(y))] \in R\}$$

$$ \sin^{2}x+\cos^{2}x=\sin^{2}y+\cos^{2}y$$
really, I'm very confused with the interpretation of the definition and the solution of this problem, I appreciate your solutions.

Comment: It is almost never appropriate to use both the [elementary-set-theory] and the [set-theory] tags on the same question. Review the descriptions please.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Can you help me with something else?@ArturoMagidin

Comment: If I can and want to, I will; otherwise, it is not polite to poke people when you are asking for help.

Comment: What does the notation $\overrightarrow f(R)$ mean?

Comment: This is the definition $$\overrightarrow f (R)=\{ (x,y)∈ A x A : (f(x),f(y)) ∈ R \} $$ @saulspatz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow f(R) &=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \mid[(\sin(x),\cos(x)), (\sin(y),\cos(y))] \in R\} \\
&= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \mid  \sin^{2}x+\cos^{2}x=\sin^{2}y+\cos^{2}y \} \\
&=  \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \mid 1 = 1 \} \\
&= \mathbb R\times \mathbb R
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your complement, is this enough to describe  $$\overrightarrow f $$, what are its equivalence classes @J.-E. Pin?

Comment: Yes, it has one equivalence class.

Comment: Thanks for your help @saulspatz